# Where can the latest stable SQLite provider be found?

Tags: .net, sqlite, dataprovider

I've been trying to locate a "latest stable build" of an SQLite data provider for .NET (4). Back in Nov 2012, I had found a 1.0.82.0 apparently released in 2010 (not sure where I found it anymore).

Today, I looked to see if there was anything more recent, found on SourceForge a 1.0.66.0 (http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlite-dotnet2/?source=dlp) which I was led to from another SQLite project which was labelled as "deceased". Although the 1.0.66.0 is on a page which shows a "last updated" of 2013-05-22, the version history accompanying the installation shows a date of April 2010, leaving me unsure as to what is most "up to date".

What would be the "latest stable" build of an SQLite data provider suitable for .NET 4, and where should I be looking to get it?

Comment: There was (and still is apparently), confusion about migration of the adapter to the sqlite.org site/project. Been there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "official" .NET binaries are available at [System.Data.Sqlite.org](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki).  The current version as of 6/17/2013 is 1.0.86.0.